# Make ImageView bigger when inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

In my `MainActivity.java` I have a Menu and a fragment container which, depending on what menu item the user as clicked, will change the fragment to that specific area. Well, this is the normal way to work with menus so I'm sure you are already familiarized. In my `HomeFragment.java` I have some cards showing an image of a country and the respective country name. If you [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yllJA.gif), you can see a .gif of that.
In order to achieve this, I have a `ViewPager` which shows a `CardStackFragment.java` (this is where the **ImageView** and the **TextView** with the country name are). **Basically, I want to change the ImageView dimensions because it is too small...** How can I make it bigger? I've tried to change its dimensions by dragging and I couldn't achieve what I wanted.
I will add here my `fragment_card.xml` and my `fragment_home.xml`.
Is it because of my `ConstraintLayout` that I can't seem to change the ImageView size?

`fragment_card.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgFotoPais"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtPaisNome"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"

    android:textSize="28sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.321"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.982" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`fragment_home.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"

>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtHomeDesc"
    android:layout_width="278dp"
    android:layout_height="26dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
    android:text="@string/sloganHome"
    android:textColor="#323B45"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtHomeTitulo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="31dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txtHomeDesc"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtHomeDesc"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-59dp"
    android:text="@string/ExploreTitulo"
    android:textColor="#323B45"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.108"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.025" />


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPagerHome"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtHomeDesc">


</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This is a good and detailed question... I hope you guys can answer me...

Answer (score 0):

In your `fragment_home.xml` your `ViewPager` height is set to

```
android:layout_height="400dp"
```

So your maximum height for `fragment_card.xml` layout is only `400dp`.
If you want to make `ImageView` bigger you need to increase `ViewPager` height.